# Java Arrays pass by reference

Tags: java, arrays

I wonder why the output is still `1,2,3,4,5`, since if I change a value in `doIt` (for example : `z[0] = 10`), the array is changed.

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
        testIt.doIt(array);

        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
}

class testIt
{
    public static void doIt(int [] z){
        z = null    
    }
}
```

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value/40523#40523

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

`doIt` is passed a copy of the array reference and can't change the original reference and make no difference to original array.

Answer (score 1):

`doIt` is passed a copy of the array reference, so it can't change the original reference (stored in the `array` variable). It can only change the state of the object referred by this reference. Therefore setting `z` to null inside `doIt` makes no difference outside the method.